# Excel vba script: find() returns nothing on 2nd iteration

Tags: vba, excel, find

```
For active_row = 9 To last_row

    ws1_func_loc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws1).Cells(active_row, "C").Value
    ws1_mat_id = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws1).Cells(active_row, "D").Value
    ws1_mat_qty = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws1).Cells(active_row, "I").Value
    ws1_reason2 = ""


    zc_sum = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("F:F"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("K:K"), ws1_func_loc, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("N:N"), ws1_mat_id, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("S:S"), "ZC")
    zk_sum = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("F:F"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("K:K"), ws1_func_loc, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("N:N"), ws1_mat_id, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("S:S"), "ZK")


    'some other If conditions...


    ElseIf zc_sum = 0 And zk_sum > 0 Then

        row_match_count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("K:K"), ws1_func_loc)

        Set found = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("K:K").Find(What:=ws1_func_loc) 'find() found nothing on 2nd iteration

        For i = 1 To row_match_count

            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Cells(found.Row, "N").Value = ws1_mat_id And ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Cells(found.Row, "S") = "ZK" And Not found Is Nothing Then

                 ws1_reason2 = ws1_reason2 & Chr(10) & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Cells(found.Row, "R").Value & ", " & "qty " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Cells(found.Row, "F").Value & ", " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Cells(found.Row, "U").Value & ", " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Cells(found.Row, "W").Value

                 Set found = Sheets(ws2).Range("K:K").FindNext(After:=found)

        Else

                Set found = Sheets(ws2).Range("K:K").FindNext(After:=found)

        End If

    Next i

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws1).Cells(active_row, "O").Value = ws1_reason2


    ElseIf .......
```

I am trying to do a multi criteria search whereby I am finding all the rows in worksheet 2 (`ws2`) which matches the values in a specific row in worksheet 1 (`ws2`).

It works during the first `For` loop iteration, i.e. `active_row = 9`, but during the second iteration, i.e. when `active_row = 10`, `Set found = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("K:K").Find(What:=ws1_func_loc)` returns `Nothing`.

But there is definitely at least a match because `row_match_count` comes up with a value greater than 0.

Comment: it's weird, I do some test and each of them succeed. Could you give the value of `ws1_func_loc`, the exact value of `Sheets(ws1).Cells(active_row, "C")` and the equivalent you should find in `Sheets(ws2).Range("K:K").Find(What:=ws1_func_loc)`

Second thought: in your macro, do you change the Workbook target anytime ?

Comment: The only thing I can see initially is that you're not specifying the workbook the second time - try using: `Set found = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("K:K").FindNext(After:=found)`

Comment: A shot in the dark: Please use all parameters `what:=ws1_func_loc, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False` and try again? Change `xlPart` to `xlWhole` if required...

Comment: @MaximePorté the values are all in the format: TRF964564-700222-01-066. i did not change workbook at anytime.

Comment: Not a revelant information for your problem, but you could clean your code by replacing all of `Sheets(ws2).Range("K:K")` by `dim colK as range: set colK = Sheets(ws2).Columns("K")` then refer range by colK. it would be cleaner (but as I said, it's not revelant to solve your problem)

Comment: Try to reduce your problem. Create a test sub with only 1st loop on `active_row = 9 To last_row`, `ws1_func_loc = ...`, `row_match_count = ...` and `Set found = ... ` it'll indicate if the problem come from the Set or from an other part of the code

Comment: @SiddharthRout lol, i think that did the trick. put it down as an answer so i can acknowledge it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout it worked the first time i ran it but now it doesn't work again. same problem. maybe because my buffer/memory or something got screwed up by the 1.5k rows in `ws1` and 6k rows in `ws2`?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what's wrong.

There is a bunch of drop down list in `ws2` which will filter the results.

If I used the drop down list to filter the rows, `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("K:K").Find(What:=ws1_func_loc)` will only be able to see/find from the filtered results, while `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws2).Range("K:K"), ws1_func_loc)` is still able to see the whole worksheet.